# hadoop distcp using subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, python-2.7, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to run hadoop distcp command using subprocess.Popen in python and get error - Invalid input. The same command runs fine if I run as Hadoop command.

Hadoop command:

```
hadoop distcp -log /user/name/distcp_log -skipcrccheck -update hdfs://xxxxx:8020/sourceDir hdfs://xxxxx:8020/destDir
```

In python:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
proc1 = Popen(['hadoop','distcp','-log /user/name/distcp_log -skipcrccheck -update', 'hdfs://xxxxx:8020/sourceDir', 'hdfs://xxxxx:8020/destDir'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

log message:

```
INFO tools.OptionsParser: parseChunkSize: blocksperchunk false
INFO tools.DistCp: Input Options: DistCpOptions{atomicCommit=false, syncFolder=false, deleteMissing=false, ignoreFailures=false, overwrite=false, append=false, useDiff=false, useRdiff=false, fromSnapshot=null, toSnapshot=null, skipCRC=false, blocking=true, numListstatusThreads=0, maxMaps=20, mapBandwidth=100, sslConfigurationFile='null', copyStrategy='uniformsize', preserveStatus=[], preserveRawXattrs=false, atomicWorkPath=null, logPath=null, sourceFileListing=null, sourcePaths=[-log /user/name/distcp_log -skipcrccheck -update, hdfs://xxxxx:8020/sourceDir], targetPath=hdfs://xxxxx:8020/destDir, targetPathExists=true, filtersFile='null', blocksPerChunk=0, copyBufferSize=8192}
ERROR tools.DistCp: Invalid input:
org.apache.hadoop.tools.CopyListing$InvalidInputException: -log /user/name/distcp_log -skipcrccheck -update doesn't exist
```

It considering the options as the source directory.
How to tell the subprocess these are options and should not be considered as source(sourcePaths=[-log /user/name/distcp_log -skipcrccheck -update, hdfs://xxxxx:8020/sourceDir] )?

I am using Python2.7 and do not have access to pip install and its Kerberos cluster.
Wanted to run this command for intra-cluster transfer but before that wanted to try this simple command within cluster.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split **all** arguments of your command line into separate elements of Popen first argument list:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
proc1 = Popen(['hadoop','distcp','-log', '/user/name/distcp_log', '-skipcrccheck', '-update', 'hdfs://xxxxx:8020/sourceDir', 'hdfs://xxxxx:8020/destDir'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) you can find `Popen` documentation, saying that `args` should be a list created by splitting all arguments by `' '`.