# Is there any way to call "hadoop cp/distcp" from python except subprocess.Open?

Tags: python, hdfs

I need to periodically move files from on-premise cluster to GCP and back using python.

While [`hdfs`](https://pypi.org/project/hdfs/) seem fine to me for discovering directories structure, I found out that it does not provide "copy" option ([limitations of WebHDFS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39405646/9145106), as far as I understand).

Before falling to the option with [`subprocess.Open`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51153956/9145106), is there any alternative (e.g. some python API) to copy files from one location to another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While looking for an answer, I found at least two possible options: [Pydoop](https://crs4.github.io/pydoop/api_docs/hdfs_api.html#pydoop.hdfs.cp) and [pydistcp](https://github.com/yassineazzouz/pydistcp).

Despite that, I decided to use `subprocess` in my case:

```py
from subprocess import check_call


def distcp(from_path: str, to_path: str) -> None:
    check_call(['hadoop', 'distcp', from_path, to_path], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

As far as I can see, Pydoop [reads and writes files via local buffer](https://github.com/crs4/pydoop/blob/develop/pydoop/hdfs/__init__.py#L149-L161), same applies to pydistcp, that's not as effective as MR job in case of big files (gigabytes).

Maybe it's possible to run `distcp` via [Pydoop MR API](https://crs4.github.io/pydoop/api_docs/mr_api.html), but such solution would be far from being simple and maintainable.